# Excel workday function to skip custom array of holidays

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I am trying to use the Excel "workday" function to assist with handling a large list of public and organisational holidays when scheduling education courses in a multi-state country (Australia). However, the large list of holidays contains locale-specific holidays! So, some holidays apply only to particular States, while others to all States (these are listed out for each state when applicable).

I'm looking for assistance to formulate a way to select/filter the array of holidays to the specific state I'm looking at while maintaining the list in a single table. If using an INDEX-MATCH type input, then I only return a single value. And this doesn't work if there are multiple sequential holidays.

For example, hypothetically, if I try to schedule an Tasmanian event on Easter Monday, the next working day will be the Wed (Tas have Easter Tue as a holiday), while other states could have an event on Tue (as no public holiday).

Is it possible to create a dynamic array in Excel to input to the Workday function?

[image: Example data]

Comment: Is the input going to be a start date, number of days and a State? e.g. what will be the workday 6 days after 18-Apr-19 for say state TAS?

Comment: If a holiday is nationwide, will that be listed any differently?  Or will there be a separate line item for each state/holiday combination.

Comment: perform your work day count without the special holidays in it, then determine the number of days between your start and end date  and subtract that count from your work day count?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld There's a separate line for each state and duplicated per state for national holidays

Comment: @patkim yep. Am just trying to upload sample to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Ok. A little unsure of how to upload an xlsx file here!

Comment: Ok. A little unsure of how to upload an xlsx file here! 

I have a course start date of 6/1/2020 in a tab called Census Date Calc) in cell C3. In C4 I'm looking to determine three business days before that for enrolment close. The institution isnt open between Christmas day and 6/1 (in all states). The holidays are specified state by state in a separate Tab (Holidays). As mentioned, some states have different holidays so I need to look state by state.

The formula I tried was =WORKDAY(C3,-3,INDEX(Holidays!$D:$D,MATCH('Census Date Calc'!B3&WORKDAY(C3,-3),Holidays!$A:$A&Holidays!$D:$D,0)))

Comment: This is saved as as CMD-SHIFT-ENTER. In B3 I have the jurisdiction, e.g. VIC. But it only returns a single value from the lookup, whereas I need the array/database of the state specific dates.

Comment: @ForwardEd I think that would only work if the hols were during the course, and if I was using a separate table for state specific hols. in this case I'm counting backwards! So need to test each the days before the start date. I was trying to avoid having a separate table for each of the states. But I may have misunderstood.

Comment: I misunderstood the question.  You can however get a count of holidays that are between your two dates for a specific date using: `=SUMPRODUCT((somesheet!B3=holsheet!($A$1:$A$20))*(somesheet!$C$3<=holsheet!$D$1:$D$20)*((somesheet!$C$3-3)>=holsheet!$D$1:$D$20))`

Comment: If you sorted your holiday table by state instead of by holiday/date, then you could define a dynamic range  for holidays.  And here is the other shoe drops.  for a range  type holidays like your Christmas period. Each of the days would need to be added to your list, and for holidays that affect all states I currently envision you having to enter the for all states in the table like it appears to have been done for ANZAC and EASTER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASSUMPTIONS:

- Holiday list is sorted by state
- Holidays that affect all states are entered for each state
- Holidays that are a range (ie more than 1 day) have each day entered in the list

Determine the start row for your state holiday list:

```
AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(holsheet!$A$1:$A$20)/(somesheet!$B$3=holsheet!$A$1:$A$20),1)
```

Determine the end row for you state holiday list:

```
AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(holsheet!$A$1:$A$20)/(somesheet!$B$3=holsheet!$A$1:$A$20),1)
```

Use INDEX to get the cell address of the appropriate row

```
INDEX(holsheet!D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(holsheet!$A$1:$A$20)/(somesheet!$B$3=holsheet!$A$1:$A$20),1)):INDEX(holsheet!D:D,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(holsheet!$A$1:$A$20)/(somesheet!$B$3=holsheet!$A$1:$A$20),1))
```

you could set that as a named formula such a STATE_HOLIDAYS and then in your workday function just reference STATE_HOLIDAY instead of the big ugly formula.

```
=WORKDAY(C3,-3,STATE_HOLIDAYS)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Holiday Table` with a column for the Holidays, and another for the State, you can use this to create an array of the relevant holidays *(actually, an array of the relevant holidays and `0`'s; the `0`'s will be ignored by the Holidays argument in the function)*

```
(HolidayTbl[State]=myState)*HolidayTbl[Holidays]
```

*(I used structured references with the Table, but you can convert them to normal references if you don't want to use a Table)*

The formula would then be:

```
=WORKDAY(StartDate,NumDays,(HolidayTbl[State]=myState)*HolidayTbl[Holidays])
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

[image]

Comment: Very simple solution; and I learned something about named tables, too! The sumproduct command seems to be a goto for array stuff! Very elegant!

Comment: @Gondy And sorting is not required for this solution.